# Cant push in Panel after changing table item data

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have an app that allows the user to enter a set of options and then returns the result in a table. When you click the table item it push's in a panel with more detail. The problem i'm having is that it works perfect the first time but when i go to change the set of options the table items become not select-able. I am not getting any errors in the console so don't kn whats going wrong with it. The only thing i can think is it might have something to do with the below code, do i have to clear the details.setData to allow the second search results data to be pushed through?

```
           Ext.define('FirstApp.controller.Details', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     config: {
      refs: {
        placesNavView:'placesContainer',
      },
      control: {
        'placesContainer places list':{
            itemtap:function(list,index,target,record){

    var ref = record.get('reference');
    var name = record.get('name');
    var address = record.get('vicinity');
    console.log(address);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(ref);

   Ext.Viewport.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask', message:'Please Wait...'});     

    var proxy = {
        type:'ajax',
        url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?  reference='+ref+'&sensor=true&key=123...',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'result'
          }
        }
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Details').setProxy(proxy);
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Details').load();

    console.log(proxy);

                var details = Ext.create('FirstApp.view.Details');
                details.setData(record.data);
                this.getPlacesNavView().push(details);


       Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);           
            }
         }  
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: is this code written in controller?
if yes then have you referenced the PlacesNavView

I guess you are using this inside a click event or any other event, in that case "this" will not reference the controller and hence its not pushing the data, share some more code please

Comment: Hi Mayur, it is in a controller and i have added the code above. Everything works fine when i populate the table first the time around, i can press table items and the view.Details is pushed however if i change the the data in the table the the table items cannot be pressed anymore and the view.Details is not pushed

Comment: try console.log(this.getPlacesNavView()) just before you push the view

Comment: its better that you give Id to your Nav View and use this... Ext.getCmp('NavViewId').push(details); instead of this.get....

Comment: that sorted the problem but has giving me a new problem.The Nav View is part of a Tab Panel, everything works fine first time around i can push and change tabs, the problem is when i change the data in the table i can push the details view but if i change tab when i return to Nav View it is blank

Comment: The problem was caused by adding an ID to the Nav View, so still stuck with the original problem